# Java Swing or AWT API - Setting breakpoint on global mouse click events without specifying line numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, debugging, intellij-idea

Most browser dev tools allow to set breakpoints on mouse events (without having to specify the source code line numbers) for JavaScript which can be used to find the handler(s) being executed when the event occurs.

Does something similar in functionality for Java (Swing or AWT API) exist? Or are there any commands or APIs or IDEs to accomplish this?

Comment: hmm .. don't quite understand what you _do_ know? the "special" button: is it a custom class or a single/multiple instance? Are they all using the same instance of handler or just duplicated code scattered across? Could you add a (pseudo-) code snippet to clarify the exact context? Whatever, in Eclipse we have a "find users of" (in mine shift-ctrl-G) which might (or not ;) be helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Do these folders and subfolders have names?  Do any of the package names have the word "controller" as part of the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no known command, API, IDEs, or debuggers that allow to set breakpoints on global events for Java yet.

So, manually pausing the debugger in the beginning and going through the cycle of pausing, continuing, stepping in, and stepping out seems to be the only solution at the moment to step into the event handler code.